# How can I get a relay's fingerprint?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays, atlas, torcheck

I recently checked https://check.torproject.org/ and noticed **Atlas** to get information for the **exit node**.

I want to craft and directly open the url for the relay without going through the Tor Project link above — but I need the fingerprint for that.

https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/FINGERPRINT

How can I glean the **exit's node fp** from TBB 3.5?

Answer (score 2):

Click the link that says Atlas below your exit IP. This will open up the Atlas details page for that relay.

[image]

Comment: I partly reworded the question — I hope you can do the same with your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup a relay by its IP address:
https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/82.72.118.90

Edit:

> How can I glean the fp from TBB 3.5?

The fingerprint of which relay? The relay linked on **the Tor page** is the exit you used to get to **the Tor page**. All your connections may not use the same exit node, and until you make a circuit, you have no exit node.

Edit again:

If your Tor listens to a control port, you can connect to it and issue this command:

```
getinfo circuit-status
```

For all your circuits, it lists the fingerprint and nickname of the guard, middle, and exit node.

Most likely you will have more than one circuit and more than one exit node. You don't know from where you exit until you make a connection, and actually exit from somewhere.

Comment: I thought all connections went through one exit relay node, since when I check for my external IP I always get the same IP, at least for a period of time. I scripted TBB to get a new identity and I want to make part of the script to open a site that gives details about my current IP. Atlas gives much more information since its part of the Tor Project.

Comment: I checked `getinfo info/names` but there's no direct way to get the fingerprint of the exit, or am I missing something?