# Why Atlas does not show all exit nodes Tor connect to simultaneously?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, circuit, atlas, exit-relays

At times Tor connect to several circuits (and different exit nodes) to support multiple protocol simultaneously, In these cases, why Atlas does not show all exit nodes Tor connect to simultaneously? Atlas only shows one exit node regardless of how many exit nodes is being used by Tor simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the Atlas link on check.torproject.org or on some other page, then the answer is: It links to the details for the exit node that you used to get to the page that the link is on.

This question is related: [How can I get a relay's fingerprint?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1422/how-can-i-get-a-relays-fingerprint)

Comment: Dear jobiwan, How may one observe the circuit used and exit node used for each individual action taken in Tor in the context of using TBB?

Comment: In the related question I linked to, you can find how to see all your circuits. (getinfo circuit-status) I don't think there is a way to see *in the browser* which circuit / exit was used for each individual request.

Comment: Also, it would be very creepy if a web site would know anything more about your circuits than which exit you used to connect to it.

Comment: Dear Jobiwan, Vidalia shows some circuits and exit nodes, but What one needs to know is how to relate each action with each circuit and exit node in a one to one mapping?

Comment: 1) You're changing the question.  2) Vidalia is not a web page but a local process that interrogates your Tor client through the control port, using the control protocol.  3) What mapping? You can get a list of circuits, but can you get a list of 'actions' to map?  4) What would it look like? Would each page, frame, image in your browser display an IP or Atlas link in the corner? Then what about requests to 'non displayed' content, like style sheets, scripts, json, etc..?  5) The only real way to know from where you connect to a server is if the server tells you from where it sees you connect.